# Horizontal table using Repeater

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, html-table, repeater

I'm trying to get the following table using a repeater.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Description:</td>
        <td>Start time:</td>
        <td>End time:</td>
        <td>Game type:</td>
        <td>Description:</td>
        <td>Start time:</td>
        <td>End time:</td>
        <td>Game type:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data1</td>
        <td>Data2</td>
        <td>Data3</td>
        <td>Data4</td>
        <td>Data1</td>
        <td>Data2</td>
        <td>Data3</td>
        <td>Data4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But  I can't work out how to do it. I have tried the following:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptGames" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
        <tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <td>Description:</td>
            <td>Start time:</td>
            <td>End time:</td>
            <td>Game type:</td>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SeparatorTemplate>
            </tr><tr>
        </SeparatorTemplate>
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <td><%# Eval("Description") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("StartTime") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("EndTime") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("GameType") %></td>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And it would work great if the separator template was just applied at the end.
So is the only way to get this pattern to work using individual tables for each dataitem? Or is there a way I accomplish my goal using one table?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers but they dont create the table I desire. I need the headings 2 be repeated over and over again (along with the dataitems) as shown in the example. (Remember the header template only prints once)

Comment: Oh, I got you wrong there. I updated my answer taking your comment into account

Answer (score 4):

You could try to write the header of the table in the HeaderTemplate and the rows in the ItemTemplate  ;-)

**Edit**: First, I thought you want your titles in the header only and each line represents on data item. So I suggested the following code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptGames" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Description:</td>
            <td>Start time:</td>
            <td>End time:</td>
            <td>Game type:</td>
        </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%# Eval("Description") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("StartTime") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("EndTime") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("GameType") %></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Now**, after your comment that you want to **repeat the header above every single data item**, I'd suggest the following:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptGames" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>Description:</td>
                <td>Start time:</td>
                <td>End time:</td>
                <td>Game type:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%# Eval("Description") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("StartTime") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("EndTime") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("GameType") %></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Note: The `AlternatingItemTemplate` that you used, represents a data item as well. By using this, you have the opportunity to display data items in different ways for every single item (normally you use different background colors for odd and even row numbers)

**Edit 2:**
I hope, I unterstood the question correctly this time :-)

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptGames" runat="server" OnItemCreated="rptGames_ItemCreated">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>Description:</td>
                <td>Start time:</td>
                <td>End time:</td>
                <td>Game type:</td>
                <td>Description:</td>
                <td>Start time:</td>
                <td>End time:</td>
                <td>Game type:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%# Eval("Description") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("StartTime") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("EndTime") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("GameType") %></td>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <AlernatingItemTemplate>
                <td><%# Eval("Description") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("StartTime") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("EndTime") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("GameType") %></td>
            </tr>
        </AlernatingItemTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

And in code behind (in `rptGames_ItemCreated` ), you could set the template of the footer depending on the count of your data items to `</table>` or `</tr></table>`
Note: I haven't tested this

Comment: even though you repeat the header each time, it's not 8 columns wide like the original example shows.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

**Update:** To repeat the headers (as per OP's comment), modify it like this (add more `td`s into each `tr` if you want more columns):

**Note:** Assuming that OP wants to style the headers differently, added a background color (just to give an idea).

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptGames" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr style="background-color: whiteSmoke">
              <td>Description:</td>
              <td>Start time:</td>
              <td>End time:</td>
              <td>Game type:</td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
          <tr>
            <td><%# Eval("Description") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("StartTime") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("EndTime") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("GameType") %></td>
          </tr>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Why even include the AlternatingItemTemplate? It's the same as the ItemTemplate.

Comment: @zeroef -- if he's putting <td> in the alternating item template, then he HAS to put <tr> in there to.  that's why.

Comment: @Kuru - What? Correct my if I'm wrong, but the alternating template should be something different that the ItemTemplate (ex: for alternating row color) His AlternatingItemTemplate matches the ItemTemplate exactly.

Comment: @zeroef -- yes & no...  you're right in that he doesn't *NEED*
 an alternating item template if it's formatted exactly like the item template -- but you can see he's using one anyway in the original question (which, there's nothing really wrong with that -- it just isn't necessary).  Maybe he'll get to formatting colors, etc. later.  My point was, if he's going to have an alternating row template (with <td> tags in it), then it needs to have the <tr> in it.

Comment: @zeroef: The idea is to give him something that he can copy/paste. He can later on add styles etc. to the `AlternatingItemTemplate`. I left it there as it was in OP's post. I'm still waiting to hear why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Move your table header row to the header and each of your item encapsulated in a tr

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptGames" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Description:</td>
            <td>Start time:</td>
            <td>End time:</td>
            <td>Game type:</td>
        </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
           <tr>
            <td><%# Eval("Description") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("StartTime") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("EndTime") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("GameType") %></td>
           </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `<tr>` in your item template (and also the alternating item template) (not the header).

```
<ItemTemplate>
<tr>
   <td>Description:</td>
   <td>Start time:</td>
   <td>End time:</td>
   <td>Game type:</td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Then adjust your seperator template:

```
<SeparatorTemplate>
   <tr></tr>
</SeparatorTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptGames" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <tr>
              <th>Description:</th>
              <th>Start time:</th>
              <th>End time:</th>
              <th>Game type:</th>
              <th>Description:</th>
              <th>Start time:</th>
              <th>End time:</th>
              <th>Game type:</th>
            </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td><%# Eval("Description") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("StartTime") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("EndTime") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("GameType") %></td>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <td><%# Eval("Description") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("StartTime") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("EndTime") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("GameType") %></td>
          </tr>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The only issue I have with my example is that if there is not an even number of records, then the closing`</tr>` won't be printed and the table might get out of whack. I'm sure you can check for that in the code behind and add a hack for that. Maybe a `literal` that you can modify at run-time?

**UPDATE**

That code should produce the following results with six records:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Description:</td>
        <td>Start time:</td>
        <td>End time:</td>
        <td>Game type:</td>
        <td>Description:</td>
        <td>Start time:</td>
        <td>End time:</td>
        <td>Game type:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data1</td>
        <td>Data2</td>
        <td>Data3</td>
        <td>Data4</td>
        <td>Data1</td>
        <td>Data2</td>
        <td>Data3</td>
        <td>Data4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Description:</td>
        <td>Start time:</td>
        <td>End time:</td>
        <td>Game type:</td>
        <td>Description:</td>
        <td>Start time:</td>
        <td>End time:</td>
        <td>Game type:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data1</td>
        <td>Data2</td>
        <td>Data3</td>
        <td>Data4</td>
        <td>Data1</td>
        <td>Data2</td>
        <td>Data3</td>
        <td>Data4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Description:</td>
        <td>Start time:</td>
        <td>End time:</td>
        <td>Game type:</td>
        <td>Description:</td>
        <td>Start time:</td>
        <td>End time:</td>
        <td>Game type:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data1</td>
        <td>Data2</td>
        <td>Data3</td>
        <td>Data4</td>
        <td>Data1</td>
        <td>Data2</td>
        <td>Data3</td>
        <td>Data4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

.

Comment: The table headings will be repeated every other iteration.

Comment: @brenjt - That's per the design. I read the project requirements ;)   "I need the headings 2 be repeated over and over again (along with the dataitems)"

Comment: You've got almost the same end result as Stephan Bauer except you remembered the FooterTemplate.  So the upvote is yours.